# File Encryption/Decryption with AES using Linux

Tags: linux, encryption, aes, openwrt

I'm using the [OpenWrt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenWrt) Linux distribution and I want to encrypt a file using AES.

How can I do that quickly and easily, and how can I—or someone else—decrypt it again?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The quickest and easiest way is to use `openssl` util (provided by `openssl-util` package). For example, to encrypt a file, issue the following command:

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -in file.txt -out file.enc
```

To decrypt:

```
openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -in file.enc -out file.dec
```

Comment: working on OSX, if I run the two commands you describe, on the decryption I get the error: "error writing output file" and writes an empty file.  it does ask for the password though.  what could be wrong?

Comment: when I try it on Ubuntu I get "bad decrypt"

Comment: @ekkis I have just checked these commands - it works for me. Make sure you are in a directory you have permissions to write to (e.g. `cd /tmp`) and you created source file you want to encrypt (`file.txt`) beforehand.

Comment: This may not be the best answer, at least according to https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/182277/is-openssl-aes-256-cbc-encryption-safe-for-offsite-backup

Comment: You forgot to add -pass pass:$YOUR_AES_ENCRYPTION_PASS

Answer (score 3):

The `openssl` encryption is not a good solution according to [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/182281), so please don't use it.

I've used https://www.aescrypt.com/ in the past and I was happy with it. If you want something that has been around for a while - that's not a bad start. It also has both a UI and a cli.

The fact that there is no small, easy to use and super simple cli tool for this purpose annoyed me so much that I sat down and wrote this
https://github.com/ro-tex/aes256cli. I literally wrote it while this discussion was open on my screen, so I'm making no claims as to how good of a solution it is. I just wanted something that will do what I need with zero friction and this is good enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

To encode:

```
cat 'yourfile' | openssl aes-128-cbc > 'encrypted file'
```

To decode: First, you have to remember your password which you used to encode, then:

```
cat 'encrypted file' | openssl enc -d -aes-128-cbc -k 'Your password' > 'decrypted file'
```

Comment: You can replace `cat foo |` with just `< foo`, btw.